# How can I specify the dimensions of the flex container and make the flex items to scroll within the container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have created an image gallery with flexbox but it is bigger than computer screen. This makes the flexbox to scroll. The problem is that there is a navigation bar placed above the flexbox in my page and it is getting overlapped when the flexbox scrolls up the screen. so I want the flexbox container to have a specific dimension and the items to scroll within it instead of the whole box to scroll over the screen. Please suggest a solution.

```css
.gallery_container {
  background-color: rgba(243, 239, 236, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
}

.gallery_header {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: calibri;
}

.photo_container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;  
}

.photo_container img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 45%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="gallery_container">
    <h2 class="gallery_header">Gallery</h2>
    <div class="photo_container">
        <img src="photoA.jpg">
        <img src="photoB.jpg">
        <img src="photoC.jpg">
        <img src="photoD.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: add a max-height or specific height and declare an overflow rule.

Answer (score 0):

I added some more photos to your `photo_container`. This way, it will be possible to see the scrolling effect better at all sizes of the screen.

To restrict the height of the `photo_container`, you need to add a `height` attribute to the class. As long as this `height` is less than the height of the screen viewport then it will be good. You can try one of the following, for example:

```css
    height: 200px;
    height: 50%;
    height: 75vh;
```

`height: 50%;` does not work because there is no `height` set on its parent, `gallery_container`. But the other two work well depending on your use case. Let's set `height: 75vh;` which means a height of 75% of the viewport height, which may be what you want,

The `photo_container` is now a good size, but all of the images are overflowing the container.

To fix that you need to create a scrollbar on your `photo_container` `div` by adding `overflow-y: scroll;` to the class. And that should work for you.

You can read the [MDN docs about CSS values and units including vh](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) here.

You can read the [MDN docs about overflow-y](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-y) here.

Here is your code with the above changes made:

```css
.gallery_container {
  background-color: rgba(243, 239, 236, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
}

.gallery_header {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: calibri;
}

.photo_container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 75vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.photo_container img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 45%;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery_container">
  <h2 class="gallery_header">Gallery</h2>
  <div class="photo_container">
    <img src="photoA.jpg">
    <img src="photoB.jpg">
    <img src="photoC.jpg">
    <img src="photoD.jpg">
    <img src="photoA.jpg">
    <img src="photoB.jpg">
    <img src="photoC.jpg">
    <img src="photoD.jpg">
    <img src="photoA.jpg">
    <img src="photoB.jpg">
    <img src="photoC.jpg">
    <img src="photoD.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```